# What's meant by result errors of SmsManager?

Tags: android

When I send an SMS using `SmsManager`, the result intent broadcasted holds a value of 5

```
Activity.RESULT_OK
SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE
SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE
SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU
SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF
```

What's meant by every one of them? and please mention a test case that could generate each one.
I know that RESULT_OK denotes a successfully sent SMS. GENERIC_FAILURE occurs for general erros (e.g. I've no credit).

But I've activated Airplane mode and tried to send an SMS. I've thought it would trigger NO_SERVICE error, but a RADIO_OFF was triggered instead. Also the official documentation is not demonstrating them very well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's my comments on the [documentation of SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE):

- `RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE`: *Generic failure cause*

  Something went wrong and there's no way to tell what, why or how.
- `RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE`: *Failed because service is currently unavailable*

  Your device simply has no cell reception. You're probably in the middle of nowhere, somewhere inside, underground, or up in space. Certainly away from any cell phone tower.
- `RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU`: *Failed because no pdu provided*

  Something went wrong in the SMS stack, while doing something with a [protocol description unit (PDU)](http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/) (most likely putting it together for transmission).
- `RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF`: *Failed because radio was explicitly turned off*

  You switched your device into airplane mode, which tells your device exactly "turn all radios off" (cell, wifi, Bluetooth, NFC, ...).

In the end, most apps need not care *why* sending an SMS failed (except ask the user if airplane mode is on in case of `RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF`), because there's nothing the app itself can do to remedy it.

Comment: @Philipp R "or up in space"... :)

Answer (score 5):

It should be possible to know more about the reason behind RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE. In the receiver which catches the outcome of the SMS send:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Other code processing other outcomes

    if (getResult() == SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE) {
        int errorCode = intent.getIntExtra("errorCode", -1);
        if (errorCode != -1) {
            // process errorCode ...
            }
        }

    // More code ...
    }
```

I have yet to prove it, but the lists provide [here](http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/gsmerrorcodes/) and [here](https://www.nowsms.com/gsm-modem-cms-error-code-list) provide what may be an explanation of `errorCode`. The acronymns [here](https://www.simsurprise.co.uk/articles/1118-mobile-phone-abbreviations) provide some explanation of how to understand those lists. For example:

Number issues

- 1 The number you are sending to is simply not used by anyone.
- 28 The number you are sending to exists, but no phone is associated with it. It's not allocated to a SIM card at the moment.
- 195 The number you are sending to is not valid.
- 196 The number you are sending to is barred to (or by, unclear) you.

Other issues

- 42 The network is too busy
- 38 The network is out of order (probably for a while)

It seems to me that there is quite some overlap between the codes, but I'm not an expert in these things.

Answer (score 4):

**SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE**

Most often this error arises when the message too long for 1 SMS. In such situation use this:

```
ArrayList<String> texts = smsManager.divideMessage(text);
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phone, null, texts, null, null)
```

Comment: I am sorry that something went wrong and there's no way to tell what, why or how. 
Test and fill...